# RegExp: Remove last period in string that can contain other periods (dig output)

Tags: python, regex, find

I am trying to parse the output of the linux [dig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_(command)) command and do several things on one shot with regular expressions.

Let's say I dig the host `mail.yahoo.com`:

```
/usr/bin/dig +nocomments +noquestion \
    +noauthority +noadditional +nostats +nocmd \
    mail.yahoo.com A
```

This command outputs:

```
mail.yahoo.com.                   0  IN  CNAME  login.yahoo.com.
login.yahoo.com.                  0  IN  CNAME  ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.
ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.       0  IN  CNAME  ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.
ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.      0  IN  CNAME  any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.
any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net. 12  IN  A      98.139.21.169
```

What I'd like to is finding all the `<host>`, `<record_type>` and `<resolved_name>` parts without the final period using only one regular expression

For this particular example with `mail.yahoo.com`, it'd be:

```
[
    ('mail.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'login.yahoo.com'),
    ('login.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com'),
    ('ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net'),
    ('ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net', 'CNAME', 'any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net'),
    ('any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net', 'A', '98.139.21.169'),
]
```

But it turns out that the `dig` command might be showing a period at the end of the name:

```
    mail.yahoo.com. 
        ^     ^   ^
        |     |   |
  Good dot    |   |
              |   |
        Good dot  |
                  |
           (!) Baaaad dot
```

Doing a regular expression that splits `dig`'s output and returns the name with the final period is fairly straightforward:

```
regex = re.compile("^(\S+).+IN\s+([A-Z]+)\s+(\S+)\.*\s*$",re.MULTILINE)
```

But calling `.findall` with that regex does return the final period in the host, because `\S+` will match the last period as well:

```
[
    ('mail.yahoo.com.', 'CNAME', 'login.yahoo.com.'),
    ('login.yahoo.com.', 'CNAME', 'ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.'),
    ('ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.', 'CNAME', 'ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.'),
    ('ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.', 'CNAME', 'any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.'),
    ('any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.', 'A', '98.139.21.169'),
]
```

So I'd need *something* that matches all non-spaces `\S` except if it's a period followed by a whitespace.

I've done endless tries, and I haven't been able to come up with a decent solution.

Thank you in advance!

**PS:**
I know I can always use the "easy" regular expression and (on a second pass) remove the last dot of the found string, but I'm curious about whether this can be done with a regular expression in one shot.

Comment: A simple change to your regex gets you the desired result `regex = re.compile("^(\S+)\..+IN\s+([A-Z]+)\s+(\S+)\.\s*$",re.MULTILINE)` Note that I'm explicitly matching the dot character at the beginning and the end.

Comment: This doesn't work because sometimees there is no period at the end of the resolved name (for instance 98.139.21.169). But I believe abarnert and I proposed some working solutions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern with multiline modifier:

```
^([^ ]+)(?<!\.)\.?[ ]+[0-9]+[ ]+IN[ ]+([^ ]+)[ ]+(.+(?<!\.))\.?$
```

Groups stored in $1 $2 and $3

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/JisUlMLAL0)

Edit:  Try this:

```
^([^ \t]+)(?<!\.)\.?[ \t]+[0-9]+[ \t]+IN[ \t]+([^ \t]+)[ \t]+(.+(?<!\.))\.?$
```

Comment: This is pretty close, but it seems to have problems dealing with tabs.

Answer (score 2):

> But calling `.findall` with that regex does return the final period in the host, because `\S+` will match the last period as well…

There are two problems here.

First, once you're escaping things with backslashes, you need to use raw string literals (`r"…"`), or you have to escape the backslashes too. I'm not actually sure whether any of your backslash-prefixed characters happen to match Python backslash-escape sequences, but that in itself is enough reason to use a raw-string literal, so your readers don't have to look up the exact rules.

Second, the general case of this problem is that regex repeats are [greedy](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) by default: they will match as much as possible while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match; when you want them to match as *little* as possible while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match, you need to add a `?` after the `+` or `*`.

In your particular case, the `\S+` can match everything up to and including the final `.`, and the `\.*\s*` will successfully match 0 `.`s and 0 spaces. but `\S+?` will leave the final `.` for the next part of the pattern. You can also force the period out of the first group by appending a period after it. Like so:

```
^(\S+)\..+IN\s+([A-Z]+)\s+(\S+?)\.*\s*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2b1_JafSMDlU--4_)

Comment: Sorry I'm not sleeping so I end up doing the same questions as you. I hope you don't mind ;(

Answer (score 2):

You can simply force that there is no period at the end of your group (and that it contains no space) :

```
npg = '([^\.\s]+(?:.[^\.\s]+)*)' #not_period_ending_group
regex = re.compile("^" + npg + ".+IN\s+([A-Z]+)\s+" + npg +".+$",re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: @abarnert makes a good point about using raw string (in this case it is not needed but it's good practice, I don't put them because I'm lazy to add 4 r, but do it on production code.)

Comment: I'm a bit torn about what answer should I choose... This is closer to my initial regexp idea, but abarnet's explanation might be useful for other OPs...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer i suggest to use `str.split()`,
if you have your string lines in a list like `L` you need this :

```
[(line[0][:-1],line[3],line[4][:-1]) for line in L]
```

Note that `[:-1]` remove the last `.` from host address !

Comment: I really have the impression that there is also an unwanted period at the end of first group (therefore line[0][:-1]), am I wrong here ?