# Grouping text lines so if A=B and B=C, then A=C

Tags: python, sorting, text, merge

I'm currently dealing with parsing the output of the [dig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_(command)) command. That command outputs the canonical names and then it outputs the actual IP of the last record.

For instance, resolving `dig mail.yahoo.com` does the following:

```
borrajax@borrajax.kom /tmp/ $ dig @8.8.8.8 @4.2.2.2 +nocomments \
     +noquestion +noauthority +noadditional \
     +nostats +nocmd mail.yahoo.com

mail.yahoo.com.     0   IN  CNAME   login.yahoo.com.
login.yahoo.com.    0   IN  CNAME   ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.
ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com. 0   IN  CNAME   ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.
ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net. 0  IN  CNAME   any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.
any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net. 49 IN  A   98.139.21.169
```

So I want to be able to say `mail.yahoo.com` resolves to `98.139.21.169`, and in order to do that, I'd need to "merge" `mail.yahoo.com` into `login.yahoo.com`, then `login.yahoo.com` into `ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com`... etc... until reaching the last `A` record.

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497803/regexp-remove-last-period-in-string-that-can-contain-other-periods-dig-output) I already got a good regexp to parse `dig`'s output, so I can have those lines nicely cleaned and stored into a list:

```
[
    ('mail.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'login.yahoo.com'),
    ('login.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com'),
    ('ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net'),
    ('ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net', 'CNAME', 'any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net'),
    ('any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net', 'A', '98.139.21.169')
]
```

The question is: How could I do it efficiently, and in a general manner, so if I have some other random lines between the `CNAME`s, it would also work:

```
[
    ('mail.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'login.yahoo.com'),
    ('foo.com', 'CNAME', 'baz.com'),    # Wooops, watch out!
    ('login.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com'),
    ('ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net'),
    ('baz.com', 'A', '204.236.134.199'), # Wooops, watch out!
    ('ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net', 'CNAME', 'any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net'),
    ('any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net', 'A', '98.139.21.169')
]
```

The desired output for that is that:

- `mail.yahoo.com` resolves to `98.139.21.169`
- `foo.com` resolves to `204.236.134.199`

Sure, I could go checking all the `CNAMES` and what it actually resolves to every time I found one, but that's gonna be `O(n^2)`... and it's horrible.

I'm sure there's a better way, but I can't think on any. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Does the first/original query's ip address(the one you want) always appear as the last item of all the text like that??

Comment: Also, in your example of encountering another, undesired address, and it's eventual ip, I notice that it's kind of nested within the original query and resolve, is that always the case?

Comment: It does, but this particular "issue" made me think on how to solve this in a more random scenario

Comment: random as in that sometimes not being the case? And other ip's coming after it?

Comment: Yeah, like... A totally unsorted crazy output :-)

Comment: Ok :) But can that happen?

Comment: Mmmmnnnno... Not in this particular scenario (but that's just because of how `dig` works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution (see the comments for more information about the algorithm):

```
import copy

def resolve(arr):
    # create an index for easy access of the urls
    index = {item[0]: item[2] for item in arr}
    # copy the index 
    mapping = copy.copy(index)

    # loop through the index
    for index_key in index: 
        # get the current value
        value = index[index_key]
        # loop through the mapping as long as the final ip address is reached
        # but only if this url wasn't found before
        while value in mapping:
            # remember the new key (so it can be deleted afterwards)
            key = value
            # get the new value
            value = mapping[key]
            # save the found value as the new value (for later use)
            # this reduces the complexity (-> better performance)
            mapping[index_key] = value
            # delete the "one in the middle" out of the mapping array
            # so that the next item don't have to search for 
            # the correct mapping (because the mapping has been found already)
            del mapping[key]

    return mapping
```

And with this script you can see that it generates the same output no matter how the list is sorted:

```
import random

data = [
    ('mail.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'login.yahoo.com'),
    ('foo.com', 'CNAME', 'baz.com'),    # Wooops, watch out!
    ('login.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com'),
    ('ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net'),
    ('baz.com', 'A', '204.236.134.199'), # Wooops, watch out!
    ('ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net', 'CNAME', 'any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net'),
    ('any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net', 'A', '98.139.21.169')
]

# test 50 times
for x in xrange(50):
    # shuffle the data array
    random.shuffle(data)

    print resolve(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I had something like this in mind (it did actually involve a `list` and `pop` which would be the equivalente to the `while/del` construct... This is still potentially `O(n^2)`, right?

Comment: I think the complexity is more like O(2n log(n)), because I save the already found url in the mapping array. This reduces the complexity, but I don't know if this can be described with log or something else in the O notation...

Comment: See the comments in the source code for more details about the complexity reduction

Answer (score 1):

I'd build a `dict` and resolve the chains from there:

```
data = [
    ('mail.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'login.yahoo.com'),
    ('foo.com', 'CNAME', 'baz.com'),    # Wooops, watch out!
    ('login.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com'),
    ('ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com', 'CNAME', 'ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net'),
    ('baz.com', 'A', '204.236.134.199'), # Wooops, watch out!
    ('ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net', 'CNAME', 'any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net'),
    ('any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net', 'A', '98.139.21.169')
]

data = { t[0]:t[1:] for t in data }

def lookup(host):
    record_type = None
    while record_type != 'A':
        record_type, host = data[host]
    return host

assert lookup('mail.yahoo.com') == '98.139.21.169'
assert lookup('foo.com') == lookup('baz.com') == '204.236.134.199'
```