# Regex/Sql script for find string that doesnot contains period[.]

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, replace, find

I have codes like V82.50, V82.75 which is fine. I have 15000+ codes where I have to find out the codes like V83 or whatever that doesnot contains period[.].

I just need to embed .00 to such strings.

I tried some combinations to find but failed.

Note:- I have these codes in my Sql table, so Sql script for same will be welcome. I have Sql 2005.

I tried to modify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497803/regexp-remove-last-period-in-string-that-can-contain-other-periods-dig-output) but no help.

Comment: You just want all values not containing period character?
    where columnname not like '%.%'

Or do they also have to begin with V*nn*?

Comment: What @jarlh said, and if you want to be more specific you could do `update tablename set columnname = columnname + '.00' where columnname like 'V[0-9][0-9]'`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this.
Just use [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx).

Example:

```
update tbl
   set clmn = clmn + '.00'
 where charindex('.', clmn) <= 0
```